# How can I test class method that creates instance?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have such a class:

```
class BaseService
  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end
end
```

I need to test that #self.call creates new instance with given arguments and sends it :call message.
How is it possible?
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following

```
let(:arguments) { [:foo, :bar] }
let(:base_service) { instance_double('BaseService') } 

before do 
  allow(BaseService).to receive(:new).with(*arguments).and_return(base_service)
  allow(base_service).to receive(:call).with(no_args)
end

it "does the expected thing" do
  BaseService.call(*arguments)

  expect(BaseService).to have_received(:new).with(*arguments).once
  expect(base_service).to have_received(:call).once
end
```

Another (and perhaps better) option might be to test that `BaseService.call(*arguments)` has the expected output or side-effects. But because you didn't write what `new(*args).call` actually does I cannot make a suggestion for that.

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) The `.to receive(:call)` could be improved by specifying *how* the `call` method should be invoked. In this case, I suppose it should be `.with(no_args)`. (2) The `.and_return(nil)` is redundant, and potentially misleading. (Can that method actually return `nil`? And even if it can, there's nothing in the spec that's verifying anything about the return value.)

Comment: @TomLord Great suggestions. I updated my answer. Thank you.